# update browser url without reload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to update browser url without page being submitted.The URL can be anything, like xyz..Please help me.Thanks in advance.

This is what i have done so far.

```
if (history.pushState)
{                    
    window.history.pushState({ "html": response.html, "pageTitle": response.pageTitle }, "", urlPath);
}
else
{
    window.location.pathname = urlPath;                            
}
```

But the page reloads by using this. Why ? can anyone help me
According to this article, pushstate wont refresh page
http://spoiledmilk.com/blog/html5-changing-the-browser-url-without-refreshing-page/#comment-6552

Comment: Shouldn't pushState take 3 strings as arguments? (Not 1 object and 2 strings)

Comment: Open this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LaazN/ and post what message is showing to you.

Comment: I used that code it worked for me window.history.pushState("object or string", "Title", 'BookAHotel' + hotelSelect);

Comment: @  user2727841 : -well it works, but a second request goes. which i want to prevent. @Ali: i got the code from the post u mentioned, but y a second request goes when i update the url?